# Recovering Windows 7 on new hardware without resetting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have Windows 7 installed on a hard drive I haven't used since I switched computers (motherboard was Dell Inspiron 580), and tested it only very recently, with it showing "Starting Windows", and then immediately going to a bluescreen, which I can't identify because my computer restarts almost immediately. I''ve tried enabling boot logging by pressing F8, to no avail. Keep in mind, I am also running Windows 11, and Windows 8.1 on my main drive. Here are my specs:

Motherboard: Gigabyte B660M DS3H AX DDR4
CPU: Intel Core i3-12100f
RAM: 32gb

Comment: Try to boot into VM (VMware for Windows is definitely the easiest) or from USB-SATA rather than directly on modern hardware. Both in Safe mode first. My guess is that cmd startup repair under VM is the most fluent approach. It it best to make a full Clonezilla disk backup (and to ensure it is restorable) before attempts.